# What means the URL parameter "/?gtnjs=1"?

Tags: html

What means the URL parameter "/?gtnjs=1" ?

I found a lot of different sites which use this tag. Everybody knows what the [utm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTM_parameters) parameter is for, but nobody knows the *gtnjs* parameter?
Is this *gtnjs* parameter also common as the *utm* (Urchin Tracking Module) or *gtmjs* (Google Tag Manager JavaScript) parameter?

Examples:

http://ww1.guitarnuts.com/amps/myths.php/?gtnjs=1
http://www.medibuntu.org/sources.list.d/xenial.list/?gtnjs=1

Does it related to the refresh meta tag?

```
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=http://www.medibuntu.org/sources.list.d/xenial.list/?gtnjs=1">
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

Comment: It means whatever the people developing the site wants it to mean.

Comment: I found a lot of different sites which use this tag. Everybody knows what the utm parameter is for, but nobody knows the *gtnjs* parameter?

Answer (score 1):

The URL parameter "/?gtnjs=1" stands for **G**oogle **T**ag Manager **N**o **J**ava**S**cript.

See also the html source of the pages to understand how to use it:

http://www.poptop.com/

http://www.3do.com/products/pc/heroes3/

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague but here goes, the "/gtnjs=1" is what we call a query string. There can be multiple queries which you can append to the base URL.

This is to send information to the web server which it uses for some special logic. For example: "sendsomefruitpics.com/pictures?fruit=apple&color=red"
In this case, web server will send pictures of red apples.

Also the query string itself has nothing to do with the meta tag. You can read more about that [here](http:////https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_http_equiv.asp)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know query strings ;-) I found a lot of different sites which use this tag. I thought this gtnjs parameter is also common as the utm (Urchin Tracking Module) or gtmjs (Google Tag Manager JavaScript) parameter?